# How to ignore URL parameters in Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

We have an app with millions of users but have some issues with proxies in India and Iran that manages to cache wrong or old images (way past expiration date) so we wanted to add a random ID to the end of the URLs. On the serverside we use Cloudfront and have setup Cloudfront to ignore query parameters.

But how can we configure Picasso to ignore the URL parameters but still use them when sending the request? A solution for this in Glide was mentioned here: 
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-how-to-ignore-url-query-parameters-in-cache-lookup

Is there a way to do the same in Picasso?